# cut a dataframe by a column with multi types of data and group it pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I'm trying to achieve the next query:

**how many apps are in each group: super light (<2MB) light (2MB;30MB) bulky(>30MB) and 'varies with device'**

My dataframe looks something like this:

```
app                                               category         rating  reviews   size  installs    type  price  content-rating  genres           last-updated  current-ver  android-ver 
 Football Wallpapers 4K                       ENTERTAINMENT    4.7     11661.0   4.0   1000000.0   Free  0.0    Everyone        Entertainment    2018-07-14    1.1.3.2      4.0.3 and up
Dr Driving Racer                                  GAME             4.3     183.0     68    10000.0     Free  0.0    Everyone        Racing           2018-06-14    2.1          4.1 and up
Dr. B.R.Ambedkar                                  SOCIAL           4.8     1902.0    5.2   100000.0    Free  0.0    Everyone        Social           2014-06-05    1.3          2.1 and up
Dr. Battery - Fast Charger - Super Cleaner 2018   TOOLS            4.5     101738.0  10    1000000.0   Free  0.0    Everyone        Tools            2018-07-26    2.2.82       4.0 and up
Dr. Booster - Boost Game Speed                    TOOLS            4.4     138872.0  22    10000000.0  Free  0.0    Everyone        Tools            2018-05-15    2.0.1077     4.1 and up
                                                                                                                                                                                            
...
Next Launcher 3D Theme Hit-G                      PERSONALIZATION  4.2     59.0      8.1   1000.0      Paid  1.7    Everyone        Personalization  2015-08-16    1.05         2.2 and up
Next Launcher 3D Theme Stun-BW                    PERSONALIZATION  4.4     2839.0    5.1   100000.0    Free  0.0    Everyone        Personalization  2014-01-11    1.00         2.2 and up
Nextdoor - Local neighborhood news & classifieds  SOCIAL           4.3     51502.0   20    5000000.0   Free  0.0    Teen            Social           2018-07-25    2.69         5.0 and up
Niche: College, K-12, and Neighborhood Search     LIFESTYLE        4.0     42.0      26    5000.0      Free  0.0    Everyone        Lifestyle        2018-07-06    1.0.1        4.4 and up
+Download 4 Instagram Twitter                     SOCIAL           4.5     40467.0   Varies with device    1000000.0   Free  0.0    Everyone        Social           2018-08-02    5.03         4.1 and up
Length: 7935, dtype: int64
```

The solution should be a `pandas.Series` or dataframe that looks like this

```
ranges            count
(0, 2]              43
(2, 30]             ...
(30, 10000]
varies_on_device    12
```

The problem is that I don't know how to use `pandas.cut` with objects, usually the bins array are numbers that determinate the ranges.

My approach was to:

1. take out the element of 'varies with device' group
2. delete them of the principal dataframe
3. later convert all the size elements to float
4. make a group by using the cut and the bins ranges
5. finally concat the two dataframes

but I think this is not the most optimized and quick way... hope is understandable

Comment: I think that your approach is fine. Otherwise you can use this trick: - replace _Varies with device_ with -1 -> convert to float ->gruopby cut -> replace  _Varies with device_ back

Comment: @rpanai your solution seems nice, gonna give it a try, thanks!